# Boto3: Get Folder names without files within them?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am using Boto3. I have a bucket, and within that i have a prefix, that contains directories. Those directories then contain a bunch of files.

Eg.
Bucket
Prefix
Directories (I want this) 700 items
Each directory has a 100 files

Everytime I call `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=target_dir).all()` it takes over a minute to complete, and thats because its loading every directory and its files within. Is there a way to load the directories only?

Comment: Those are not directories, they are prefixes. S3 is a flat filesystem. If you add `Delimiter=/` to your call, it will only return prefixes, but it won't be faster because it still needs to scan every object.

Comment: I wouldn't expect 7k objects to be enough to see any significant slowdown.

Comment: I would suggest prepending your `directory` name with a prefix, and then you can use prefix to filter out the directories.